# array of struct using asn.1

Tags: arrays, asn.1

Am learning to write asn.1 grammar. I wish if asn.1 provides facility to write array of sequence. It has a pattern of same type of structure repeated again and again, but with minor modification. I wonder if ASN.1 would allow me to write array kind of grammar to fit it in few rather than write this big grammar.

```
gamePlayer {
gamePlayer {
    gamePlayer type: user (0)
    playerDetail  {
        name: player_1
        team: red
        ip: 10.3.3.1
        membership: level_2
    }
}
gamePlayer {
    gamePlayer type: user (0)
    playerDetail  {
        name: player_2
        team: blue
        ip: 10.3.3.2
        membership: level_4
    }
}
gamePlayer {
    gamePlayer type: ai (1)
    playerDetail  {
        name: ai_1
        team: red
        bot: bikeBot
    }
}
gamePlayer {
    gamePlayer type: ai (1)
    playerDetail  {
        name: ai_2
        team: blue
        bot: bikeBot
    }
}
gamePlayer {
    gamePlayer type: ai (1)
    playerDetail  {
        name: ai_3
        team: blue
        bot: carBot
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This looks similar to an ASN.1 value notation. Whats the type that corresponds to this value. Also ASN.1 does neither have array nor struct. Do you mean SEQUENCE OF and SEQUENCE?

Comment: @Henry: Hope SEQUENCE OF would useful if all the sub-parameters are same for all type of `players` and `ai`. But here, only `name` and `team` is common  for all; other parameters are depends on weather it's `player` or `ai`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `ENUMERATED` for gameplayer type. Differences in playerDetail would be possible to solve with `OPTIONAL` members. Array of game players would be solved by `SEQUENCE OF`.

This is the example of ASN.1 module (I have not tested if it is correct)
GamePlayerModule

```
DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::= BEGIN

GamePlayers ::= SEQUENCE OF GamePlayer

Gameplayer ::= SEQUENCE {
   type ::=         ENUMERATED
                       {
                          user  (0)
                          ai    (1)

                       },
   playerDetail     PlayerDetail
}

PlayerDetail ::= SEQUENCE {
    name            UTF8STRING,
    team            UTF8STRING,
    ip          [0] UTF8STRING OPTIONAL,
    membership  [1] UTF8STRING OPTIONAL,
    bot         [2] UTF8STRING OPTIONAL
}

END
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to skin this cat in ASN.1. One way:

```
Player ::= SEQUENCE {
    name    UTF8String,
    team    UTF8String,

    humanOrAI CHOICE {
       human [0] HumanInfo,
       ai    [1] AIInfo
    }
}

HumanInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    ip         OCTET STRING (SIZE (4))
    membership UTF8String
}

AIInfo ::= ENUMERATED { bikeBot, carBot }
```

The use of `CHOICE` is probably a suitable way to allow you to mix such items together. (You might consider what would happen if you wanted to let humans take over an AI player.)

It's typical for IP addresses to be specified as `OCTET STRING`s in most protocols, but that's a bit of an implementation detail.

There are a good set of resources available online for learning ASN.1: see [this tutorial](http://obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/asn1only.html) for something quick; [Larmouth's](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oss.com%2Fasn1%2Fresources%2Fbooks-whitepapers-pubs%2Flarmouth-asn1-book.pdf) and [Dubuisson's](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/dubuisson-asn1-book.PDF) books are online, too. Larmouth is more accessible, but Dubuisson is probably more thorough.